# Oracle, Blob data are missing in my export file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-export

I use Oracle 11g, I am trying to export my data(only the data, not table create scripts etc.) 
So it can be imported by customer to their database

When I use Oracle Sql developer's export database, it only exports the data but my BLOB's are missing! There are a lot of image files in one of my tables which I want to export as well.

I wonder If I really need to use oracle exp imp tool;

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004777

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/dialogs.htm#RPTUG30590):

> **Format**: Select the desired output format for the data to be unloaded. Depending on the selected format, other options may appear. For example, for xls (Microsoft Excel file), you can specify worksheet names for the data and the SELECT statement.
>
> For CLOB data, exporting is supported only if the format is loader (SQL*Loader) or pdf (PDF). Some export types export only a subset of the string followed by an ellipsis (...).

It doesn't explicitly refer to BLOBs, but if CLOBs can only be exported as loader or pdf, it makes sense that BLOBs would also have that restriction. If you want to recreate this data in another schema or database, SQL*Loader format seems like a good choice.

What would you expect the `insert` statement to look like? You'd have to have a text literal containing the binary value, which is a problem in itself, but you'd also be limited to 4k - which many image files might exceed. For a CLOB it might give you the first 4903 chars followed by an ellipsis in the string literal, but I'm not sure; for a BLOB even that wouldn't make any sense.

If you want to transfer data between databases you should consider [data pump export/import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm), or if you (or your client) are restricted by server access then you could fall back to [legacy export/import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm). Both support LOBs. Data pump is superior and should be used in preference if at all possible. The only downside really is that the dump files are written to the database server and getting access to them (or permissions on a `directory` object to write to *can* be problematic in some organisations.

Comment: DO you think I need this tool? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004777

Comment: @Spring - you should look at data pump over the old export/import tools; I've updated my answer. I don't seem to have read the question properly, as I assumed you were only interested in SQL Developer options. For transfer of data to a client I'd certainly use a proper dump file rather than anything SQL Developer can produce.

Comment: tnx, this is what I need: I will create a dump/export on my local machine and local oracle database, then I want to be able to send the result(a file, a folder whatever) to the customer(bank), he runs it on his own database and get the new data installed. So which tool is better here?

Comment: @Spring - `expdp` (data pump export). You should check the client can handle a data pump dump file, and check you're on the same Oracle version; otherwise they may not be able to load the dump file you send.

Comment: tnx, When u say "check the client can handle a data pump dump file" you mean they need expertise for this?

Comment: @Spring - the need someone who can put the dump file(s) on their DB server and who can then run `impdp` using a DB account that can access the Oracle directory where the dump is, and can insert into the tables of course. Ir's more about whether their processes allow this mechanism that expertise as such. Just worth checking so you don't waste your time, perhaps.

Comment: could you have a look at this:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836657/using-oracle-exp-imp-tool

Answer (score 0):

Any LOB can't be inserted (export/import) directly as normal data.
You have to write a place/SQL block to get blob from db and write it on is.
Check out this link, this is how you exactly do it.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_writing_blob_clob_os_file.htm
Cheers mate
V

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for correcting. One column per table was before 8.

Comment: DO you think I need this tool? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004777