# Using Oracle exp imp tool

Tags: oracle, database-migration

I use Oracle 11 **on my local server**, and wanna export my data using oracle exp tool:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1023725
```

I dont have any views, triggers or stored procedures, just ordinary tables and some image blobs in one table. It should be really simple to export this.

But I really didn't understand anything how to do it;

- First of all, It says I should run the  catexp.sql or catalog.sql before I run the exp tool..Ok but where the heck is these scripts? I searched my computer bu no such thing exists.
- Second it is still not clear what needs to be done, What **.exe** exactly I need to run. And then it says;

  ```
  exp PARAMETER=value
  ```

What the heck is parameter what the heck is value?..Is there any better documentaion or anyone can explain with simple terms the steps I need to take?

Comment: Just start exp.exe, it will ask for everything. If you would like to script it you can pass arguments in the PARAMETER=value format in the command line.

Comment: @Lajos Veres at second step it fails sayuing "failed to open EXPDAT.DMP for write"

Comment: You only need to [run catexp/catalog](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004716) if they haven't been run already for some reason; they would normally exist and be run as pat of the database creation, so you probably don't need to worry about those. `PARAMETER` is a placeholder for any of the [supported parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#CEGFIAGE). There are [several export examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1006106). (You decided against data pump then?)

Comment: @Spring It tries to write to the current directory. Do you have permission for this?

Comment: It asks for the name you would like to use for backup, and it offers a default.

Comment: @Lajos Veres I have admin rights on computer

Comment: If you can't write to the directory you're in, give it a full path name to where the file should go, including its name. I think you need to try to adapt one of the examples, for the schema and objects you want to export.

Comment: There are examples at the previous link for Table mode and User mode. You can either export everything for a user (owner), or specific tables. All of this is covered in the documentation.

Comment: @Alex Poole if you enter you comments as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to [run catexp/catalog](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004716) if they haven't been run already for some reason; they would normally exist and be run as pat of the database creation, so you probably don't need to worry about those.

`PARAMETER` is a placeholder for any of [the supported parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#CEGFIAGE), as shown under ['invoking export and import'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004777).

You need to specify an export (dump) file; the default is create a file called `EXPDAT.DMP` in the current directory. If you don't have permissions to write to that directory you need to specify the full path to where you want the file to be created, including its name.

There are [several export examples], including table mode and user mode. When you run interactively and don't specify `OWNER` or `TABLES` on the command line or in a parameter file you're prompted to choose the mode, which is the 'users or tables' prompt you saw. You might want [something like this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#CEGHFFFE):

```
exp blake/paper FILE=blake.dmp TABLES=(dept, manager) ROWS=y COMPRESS=y
```

... but with your own user/password, file name (and path), and table names.

Comment: tnx, everything worked fine..only thing is I entered table names one by one to command line but I think they need to entered in a certain order(?)...so some tables didn't created correctly when I later imported it using the imp tool. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Spring - use `expdp` *8-) Why didn't they create, because of foreign key constraints maybe? Import should take care of that though if the tables don't already exist. If they do then you can do individual imports for each table (or group of tables) so they're populated i the order you expect. Or you can disable constraints during the import, but there's a slight risk you won't be able to re-enable them afterwards if the data is odd or the schemas are different.

Comment: ah wait..I should always use expdp and not imp.exe?

Comment: didnt give any error, but later when I changed the order I enter my table names it worked..so I guess there was a table needs a foreign key on some not loaded yet table..which but it should be handled by import tool..strange

Comment: @Spring - yes, I was being flippant. I'm not sure what you were doing if you didn't get an error and didn't get any tables created/populated. It will handle that if you're creating new tables, though data pump (expdp/impdp) does it more elegantly I think. It will have created a log file which might have more info, if your next attempt didn't overwrite it. But if you got there in the end then I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Comment: ah..just to be clear..can I run expdb on a dump created by the legacy exp?

Comment: No, they are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Hi again! I have a new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857177/oracle-export-tool-does-not-create-some-tables-and-sequences?noredirect=1#comment34870489_22857177