# Oracle export tool does not create some tables and sequences

Tags: oracle, data-migration

I use oracle 11, and use exp/imp tools to migrate data between databases.

It works very fine **IF** all empty tables and sequences are already created in target database.

But If tables dont exists in target DB than a few bad things happen;

- It still creates tables but only the ones with data, I couldnt find a way to force it create  empty tables in target DB.
- It does not create the sequences.

This is how I enter my values to export tool;

```
Users or Tables -> Tables
Export table data -> yes
Compress -> yes
Table or Partition to be exported -> I enter table names here one by one,
```

But it does accept table names without data..It says table does not exist, so no surprize they are not imported later.

```
Import Data only > no

Import File > Full path to Dump file.

List contents of import file > no

Ignore create error > no

import grants > yes

import table data > yes

import entire export > yes
```

Comment: exp/imp is deprecated. You should use `expdb` and `impdp`

Comment: @Alex Poole I updated the question, I use exp/imp because I figured out how it mostly works, it is easy and it (mostly) works fine, and I have no time to experiment with another tool at the moment

Comment: @Alex Poole so  Users or Tables -> Tables this chooses the mode? I thought this is for what I want to export from

Comment: "*I have no time to experiment with another tool*" - so you rather spent your time experimenting with a tool that apparently doesn't work?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "that apparently doesn't work" that's not certain yet\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequences are not exported in table mode. The [documentation lists the objects exported in each mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL3637), and that shows that sequences are only exported in user and full database modes.

Export is deprecated in 11g, as the documentation also states:

> Original Export is desupported for general use as of Oracle Database 11g. The only supported use of original Export in Oracle Database 11g is backward migration of XMLType data to Oracle Database 10g release 2 (10.2) or earlier. Therefore, Oracle recommends that you use the new Data Pump Export and Import utilities

The empty tables are not being exported if you have deferred segment creation. [This AskTom articles refers to it](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3014631100346711923), and it's also mentioned [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL2660):

> The original Export utility does not export any table that was created
>   with deferred segment creation and has not had a segment created for
>   it.

You can either use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` to get the table creation statements for all the tables, or just the empty ones, and build them manually from that; or force an extent to be allocated (as mentioned in the docs too); or use the supported and current data pump export and import. Based on previous questions you should only be using `exp/imp` if your customer refuses to handle data pump files, and I can't really think of a good justification for that.

Comment: I tried to run expdp a few times with different users actually, after I enter username password it just quits in 10 seconds, no warning nothing

Comment: Assuming oracle will not delete the segment when row is deleted, I inserted and deleted a row from my empty tables, it worked :)

Comment: @Spring - if you run `expdp` with just username/password you should get an ORA-39145 as you haven't specified a directory name. It isn't really any more complicated than `exp` for simple cases (i.e. not needing to use the advanced features that make it superior); you just need to read the manual and look at the examples.

Comment: thx! I know you will say use expdp :) but.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870845/oracle-possible-encoding-problems-when-importing-data