# Oracle: possible encoding problems when importing data

Tags: oracle

On Oracle 11, I dumped my data using exp/imp to be migrated to another DB.

I tested to import the dump file on my local database, with no problem at all.

But then my colleague tried the same on his own machine and **some tables** couldn't get imported due to the error:

```
can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.
```

I dont have any long type, but I read that this error could also be thrown when size exceeds on a varchar2 type, So I checked character sets of databases, I have default Windows charset and he has utf8 charset. So do you think maybe same length of data are represented with more bytes and this leads to this kind of error?

Do I have to change my database charset and create another dump? I look for a better solution, because this also needs to be imported to customers database, which I know has a totally different charset..

Comment: Could you confirm what's the character set of both databases: this should be seen from `select * from nls_database_parameters`. If the charset of the target database is a superset of the source one: you shouldn't need changing the charset.

Comment: @ as i said, i have oracle default windows charset(first option when you create a new db) he has utf 8.  ( second option)

Comment: "default windows charset" is something specific to your Windows regional settings - on one environment the default may be one, on another - could be different. What finally matters is what's the value of NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter. Could you check the value of this parameter in your databases?

Comment: Another question: is it an option for you to using Oracle data pump (expdp, impdp) instead of exp/imp? The exp/imp utilities have been deprecated, have some deficiencies and data pump is recommended over them.

Comment: What is the value of your `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` (on both source and target database)? Could you share the definitions of some of the problematic tables (what is important to know is what are the types of the columns).

Comment: `So do you think maybe same length of data are represented with more bytes and this leads to this kind of error?`: yes, this is likely to happen if you have varchar2 columns with values bigger than 2000 characters and if you're moving from single-byte charset to multi-byte one.

Comment: @Yavor tnx I will check on monday and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Any windows inherited character set isn't multi byte by definition. When you created multi byte(utf8) db every single character may be converted during the import to 1-3 bytes. So you have to increase automatically before import every string type column to x3 times. In case you will case the limit of 4096 use Clob type instead.

Comment: how can i do that automatically before import? also there is varchar2 set to 4000 and I can not increase it anymore. and I think it also causes a probelm at the moment

Comment: I mean you have to generate alter statements from usertabcolumns. Use CLOB data type in case you hit the limit of varchar2 or char.