# Oracle SQL developer export database LOB types

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to export an oracle database from Oracle SQL developer tool (v 1.2.1).
While I've exported the database I noticed that the LOB type columns are exported with missing fields like this :
'(CLOB) < p> text...' and not whole string.
Does anyone now how to export an oracle database from Oracle SQL developer with whole string on LOB types?

The steps I followed to export database are:

[select Tools on menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPdw.png)

[then I added this options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFdSO.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL Developer version 1.2.1 was released in 2007. You might want to install a newer version. (And also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22807316/266304) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42244941/266304).) Just curious, what database version are you trying to export from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.